# how to find all the branch type created by one person in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I created a branch type one month ago , but for some reason delayed to use it until now.  But now I just have a vague memory of the branch name but not very sure about it
. So I'm wondering if clearcase has the feature that list all the branch type create by a person, in my case just me, then I can find the exact name of the branch type I created one month ago .  Need your help, thanks in advance .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can list the brtype of a vob, displaying only what you need with [fmt_ccase](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/7.1.2?topic=information-fmt-ccase) directives:

```
cleartool lstype -kind brtype -invob \myVob
```

would be enough to do some grep, but for a more compact output:

```
cleartool lstype -kind brtype -invob \myVob -fmt "%u %Ad %N\n"
```

You would only have the username, the date and the name of the brtype, for you to grep.

Note the `%Ad` parameter: age in days, to be able to quickly spot brtype created 30 days or so ago.

Comment: '\n' didn't work for me, so I just added "User:" and other labels before the data placeholders and did a find/replace in Notepad++. Pretty crude solution, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

`cleartool lstype -kind brtype | grep username` works for me on Linux.