# Reference for properties that can be passed to -fmt?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

The [fmt_ccase](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) documentation for `cleartool` gives this as a formatting option:

> **%[p]p**
>   Property value: Displays the value of the property specified in square brackets. If multiple values are returned, they are separated by spaces.

However, the page doesn't list the possible values for `[p]` as far as I can tell, and I can't find any other reference to this anywhere in the ClearCase documentation.

I would like to use this to format output from `lstype` for scripting purposes, to print out properties of a type such as the supertype and type manager.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

Here is sample output for what I'm ultimately trying to do:

> foo
>   superfoo
>   foo_mgr

where `foo` is the type, `superfoo` is the supertype of `foo`, and `foo_mgr` is the type manager for `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find all the properties in the **[fmt_ccase page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm)**.

> Format strings for command output
>
> `-fmt` option syntax (used in various reporting commands: `annotate`, `describe`, `lshistory`, `lscheckout`, and so on):

```
-fmt "format-string"
```

> format-string is a character string, composed of alphanumeric characters, conversion specifications, and escape sequences. It must be enclosed in double quotes ( `"` ).

More precisely, the section:

```
%[p]p
```

> **Property value**: Displays the value of the property specified in square brackets. If multiple values are returned, they are separated by spaces.

For instance:

> Display the type of a file element.

```
cleartool describe -fmt "Type:  %[type]p\n"  util.c@@

Type: text_file
```

See an `lstype` example at "[How to find all the branch type created by one person in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2279712/6309)".

Comment: Thank you @VonC, but that much is clear to me.  What I don't know is the possible values for `[p]`.  In your example, you use `[type]`, but how do I know that is a property I can use?  To go back to my concrete example, I've tried `%[supertype]p`, but it doesn't print anything for that parameter.

Comment: Ahh, I see `[type]` now in _Table 1. Variants for ClearCase and ClearCase LT objects_.  But I don't see any option for printing the supertype...is it not possible?

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of output you need?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think I can probably parse the information from `lstype -l`, but it would be much more convenient if I could use `-fmt` to put it in the form above instead

Comment: The type itself is a ClearCase object that you can describe. I will check for the super type and type manager though.

Comment: @KevinK yes, I don't see anything regarding those information. Parsing the `lstype` output remains the simplest way to extract those data. My answer was about the more general aspect of your question: " the page doesn't list the possible values for `[p]`": yes, it does.