# Is cleartool output localized?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

From what I discovered in my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812257/reference-for-properties-that-can-be-passed-to-fmt), I am now attempting to parse the output from `lstype -l` in order to determine the supertype and type manager for a given element type.

My initial thought is to process the output line-by-line and look for the first line starting with `supertype:`, then take the remaining portion of the line.

However, this will only work if `cleartool` always outputs in English.  The code I'm writing could be used in a Japanese ClearCase environment, and I am concerned that a Japanese version of ClearCase may output something different from `cleartool`.  Is this a valid concern, or will `cleartool` always output in English?

Example output:

```
cleartool> lstype -l eltype:utf8_file@\vobFoo  
element type "utf8_file"  
 2012-12-03T19:08:24-06:00 by [username].None@CLEARCASE-VM  
  "Predefined element type used to represent a UTF8 file."
  owner: [computer]\[username]
  group: [computer]\None
  scope: this VOB (ordinary type)
  type manager: utf8_file_delta
  supertype: file
  meta-type of element: file element
```

Comment: Why not run `LANG=en_US cleartool` then?

Comment: @Mike are you saying to set an environment variable?  I've never seen that tried before; if it works, that would be perfect :)

Comment: Yes, normally `LANG` is used to UNIX to specify the language that should be used, IIRC.

Comment: See my edited answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13849380/6309). I have link to official documentation regarding ClearCase localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cleartool` itself is not localized **except for Japanese** (I have set LANG on many different languages - but Japanese -  without having ever seen a different output).

`xcleartool` (a GUI interface for Unix) is, as "[About en_US.UTF-8 LANG variable and its affect on xclearcase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21205626)" illustrates, or "[Rational ClearCase on the UNIX system and Linux](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_ms_platforms_guide.doc/clearcase_on_unix.htm)" details.

See "[Supported IBM Rational ClearCase configurations in multiple language environments](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/c_supp_cc_cfgs_mult_langs.htm)":

> **Rational ClearCase**
>
> - VOB servers that run English or Japanese operating systems can support:
>
>   - English clients that act as view server hosts and run English operating systems
>   - Japanese clients that act as view server hosts and run Japanese operating systems
> - VOB and view servers that run English or Japanese operating systems can support:
>
>   - English clients that run English operating systems
>   - Japanese clients that run Japanese operating systems
>
> Only CCRC GUI support more languages, ie "Group-1":
>
> - Brazilian Portuguese
> - French
> - German
> - Italian
> - Japanese
> - Korean
> - Simplified Chinese
> - Spanish
> - Traditional Chinese

So, as described in "[Setting Japanese language options](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cczose.doc/topics/t_cce_japan.htm)":

> On a Windows system set either of the following sets of environment variables:
>   In the following environment variables:

- **`C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\resdll`** is **where the Japanese message catalog is located**,
- `%L` is the environment variable you set for `LANG`, which is **`ja_JP`**, and
- `%N` is the Japanese message catalog, which is **`bccMsg.cat`**.

> Use `%%L` and `%%N` to carry out the set command within a batch file instead of `%L` and `%N`.

```
set LANG=ja_JP
set NLSPATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\resdll\%L\%N;%NLSPATH%
set RCC_CATALOG=C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\resdll\ja_JP\bccMsg.cat
```

Comment: Great find, that would be particularly useful if I could emulate a Japanese client on an English machine.  Unfortunately, when I attempted setting the environment variables, the `cleartool` output is still in English, except I get a message `Message Catalog System: corrupt file.`.  The article you linked was for modifying "Remote Build" messages...maybe it isn't meant to be used with cleartool like that

Comment: @KevinK I agree. Beside a Japanese workstation, I don't think you will see `cleartool` returning anything but English messages.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21404250) which seems to imply that it isn't localized. Quoting:

```
シンボリック・リンクを検索し、出力します。

UNIX と Linux:

2 種類の方法が存在します。

1. cleartool find -all -type l -exec '/usr/atria/bin/cleartool describe $CLEARCASE_PN'

例:
% cleartool find -all -type l -exec '/usr/atria/bin/cleartool describe $CLEARCASE_PN' 
symbolic link "/vobs/french/ctlink_import" -> import 
created 25-Feb-03.12:34:39 by Joe_USER (joeuser.syb@lemur) 
Protection: 
User : joeuser : rwx 
Group: syb : rwx 
Other: : rwx 
symbolic link "/vobs/french/slink_import" -> import 
created 16-Apr-03.14:02:17 by Joe_USER (joeuser.syb @lemur) 
Protection: 
User : joeuser : rwx 
Group: syb : rwx 
Other: : rwx
```

Two suggestions:

1. Test it in the Japanese environment! There is no substitute for
   this! ;-)
2. Use the `LANG` environment variable, if necessary, to force use of a certain language. For example, you could run `LANG=en_US cleartool` or `LANG=C cleartool`.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  [A developerWorks post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14511382&#14511382) I found, seem to suggest it sometimes can be localized.  But I'll give testing with a Japanese environment a shot, and see how it goes.

Comment: I managed to test it on a Japanese WinXP machine, and the `cleartool` output is indeed in Japanese.  However, based on the information VonC was able to provide, I'm thinking I can probably just modify my strategy to check for either the English version or Japanese version (since other languages don't seem to have this effect)