# CT protect VS vob_siddump/vob_sidwalk

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

1. Several ClearCase branch type owners have left the company and there domain ID (windows environment) got deleted.
   Should I use `cleartool protect` to change owner to CCadmin account or use `vob_siddump/vob_sidwalk` ?
2. I Found below in vob_sidwalk manual:

   ```
   -u/nknown
   ```

   > Map SIDs that cannot be resolved to an account in the domain.
   >   Any user SID that cannot be resolved is mapped to the SID of the VOB owner.
   >   Any group SID that cannot be resolved is mapped to the SID of the VOB's primary group.
   >   The mappings are written to the SID file.

If I have to use `vob_siddump/vob_sidwalk`, will `-u` resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually prefer a [`cleartool protect -chown`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protectvob.htm) to a [`vob_sidwalk/vob_siddump`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/vob_sidwalk.htm), because you don't have to dump/reload a full vob.
I use typically a combination of `ct find -exec "cleartool protect -chown"` comman, as shown in this [IBM article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146517).
For instance, [I look for user `NOBODY`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17335157/6309).

Note that with UCM, you need to change the ClearCase object *and* the ClearCase UCM object (for instance, the branch *and* the UCM stream owner.

---

> I need to change only branch type owner ship and not any element.

Then `cleartool protect` is still the way to go, you just don't need a `cleartool find`.
You just need to list those brtype:

```
cleartool lstype -kind brtype -invob \myVob
```

See "[how to find all the branch type created by one person in clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2279712/6309)".

Comment: This discussion is also relevant, and points out to `cleartool protect`: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014057204

Comment: 1. Can cleartool find command list all the branch with nobody as owner ?

Comment: @maestromani yes, by default `cleartool find` select versions from all branches. You can limit it with a `-branch`

Comment: just in case any misunderstanding, I'm mentioning again. I need to change only branch type owner ship and not any element.

Comment: @maestromani Ok, I have edited the answer to take into account brtype instead of elements in a branch.